# convert data to CSV with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm not deep involved with dictionaries in python. However, I have structured text data (ASCII) which I would like to convert to CSV (to input in a database or spreadsheet). Not all values are available in each line:

```
name Smith city Boston country USA
name Meier city Berlin ZIP 12345 country Germany
name Grigoriy country Russia
```

not all fields are in each line. However, no spaces are in the field values. How can I convert such textfile in a CSV like

```
name, city, ZIP, country
Smith, Boston, , USA
Meier, Berlin, 12345, Germany
Grigory, , , Russia
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Try the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = """name Smith city Boston country USA
name Meier city Berlin ZIP 12345 country Germany
name Grigoriy country Russia"""

keys = {}                                # will collect all keys
objs = []                                # will collect all lines
for line in d.split("\n"):               # split input by linebreak
    ks = [x for x in line.split()[::2]]  # even positions: 0, 2, 4, 6
    vs = [x for x in line.split()[1::2]] # odd positions:  1, 3, 5, 7
    objs.append(dict(zip(ks, vs)))       # turn line into dictionary
    for key in ks:
        keys[key] = True                 # note all keys

print(",".join(keys))                    # print header row
for obj in objs:
    print(",".join([obj.get(k, "") for k in keys]))
```

Output:

```
country,city,name,ZIP
USA,Boston,Smith,
Germany,Berlin,Meier,12345
Russia,,Grigoriy,
```

Getting the columns in another order is left as an exercise to the reader.